# Set Textfields max size preference but allow resize

Tags: html

I want to use couple of 270px textfields for my page.
When i resize the page just a little bit, my textfields, due to their size
override my bootstrap columns.

The problem isn't that it falls into the sm category from md.

All i want to do is, set that i want 270px for starters, but when the page is getting smaller and smaller, feel free to make it as small as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
textarea {
       width: 270px;
       max-width: 100%;
}
```

Or just:

```
textarea {
       max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Yep, i tried your second suggestion. I wanted to take the whole column space so allowing bootstrap do its thing was better. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With this code:

```
textarea {
    max-width: 270px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -o-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

if the textfield parent has width greater than 270px, it'll be displayed with 270px width, and when your page get smaller and smaller, consequently, the textfield's parent get smaller too and when it reaches a width value smaller than 270px, the textfield get smaller too.
but i think, it depends too on how your textfield is disposed on the container element, and if there is other elements in the same level as textfield.